# How to display an array like a hypertext in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to display rooms array like hypertext but after the first room is created it gives an error.

```
let rooms = [];
app.get("/rooms", function(req, res) {
    for(let i=0;i<rooms.length;i++) {
        res.send('<a href="/room/'+rooms[i]+'">'+rooms[i]+'</a> <br>');
    }
    res.send(200)
});
app.get("/room/:roomName", function(req, res) {
    let roomName = req.params.roomName;
    rooms.push(roomName);
    res.send(roomName);
});
```

Comment: When you are using ```res.send()``` http response will send, so you need prepare all data first, then send them once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is with `res.send` since it shows that server have responded to client. So you can try following code

```js
app.get("/rooms", function(req, res) {
    let responseString = "";
    for(let i=0;i<rooms.length;i++) {
        responseString += ('<a href="/room/'+rooms[i]+'">'+rooms[i]+'</a> <br>');
    }
    res.status(200).send(responseString)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below fixes your problem,

```
// Rooms must be const, didn't modified, push is enumerating not overriding.
const rooms = []

// Prefer arrow functions for better looking code
// If you don't use req, just _
app.get('/rooms', (_, res) => {
  // Map over rooms,
  const response = rooms.map(room => `<a href="${room}">${room}</a>`)
  res.send(response)
})

app.get('/room/:name', (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params
  rooms.push(name)
  res.send(name)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get('/rooms', (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json(rooms.map(room =>(`<a href="${room}">${room}</a>`)));
  } catch(error) {
     console.error(error);
     return res.status(500).json(error); // or another status you decide.
  }
})
```